# How to create autonomus jar with using other jars?

Tags: java, maven, jar

My java project is not big, actually it is a studing project, and I'm using some eclipse jars that cannot be imported by maven. So I just put them in resources folder and created dependencies.
But when I make a package it all goes wrong. It either doesn't include those dependencies, or doesn't include my src folder(!).

My project structure is:

> *src/com/myName/Main*
>
> *resources/jar1  jar2*

I use jar-with-dependencies descriptor but I seem to be lost in it. How do I fix it? Right now my src is missing in the result jar.

My pom.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProgram</artifactId>
    <build>
        <plugins>               

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>controller.MainController</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>    
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>    
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>  

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/resources/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.106.2.v20171129-0543.jar
            </systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>swing2swt</groupId>
            <artifactId>swing2swt</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/resources/swing2swt.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.ui</groupId>
            <artifactId>ide</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1-M20060915-1030</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt</artifactId>
            <version>3.106.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>    

    </dependencies>    

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to aggregate the project with its dependencies into a single distributable JAR file you can use [Apache Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). A typical configuration is as follows:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <!-- NOTE: We don't need a groupId specification because the group is
             org.apache.maven.plugins ...which is assumed by default.
         -->
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        [...]
</project>
```

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/borisredkin/java-header-updater/src/a78f536709ccab5e6e251e7d084eecbab4eb1d10/pom.xml?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) is an example usage.